# area based routing in reactjs (react-router-dom)

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to split the routing based on area, like if I am in the user section

```
http://localhost:3000/user
```

then I want to handle all the routes like

```
http://localhost:3000/user/:id
http://localhost:3000/user/create
http://localhost:3000/user/:id/edit
http://localhost:3000/user/:id/delete
http://localhost:3000/user/filtered
```

in the user component itself. But it is not working.

If I am keeping

```
 <Route path="/user" component={UserList} />
 <Route path="/user/create" component={UserCreate} />
```

inside index.js file (main file, where other routes are also defined), it is working, 
but if I am moving the routes related to User in UserList component as below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import UserCreate from './create';

class UserList extends React.Component {
   render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>user List will be here</h1>
                <Link to="/user/create">create User</Link>
                <Route path="/user/create" component={UserCreate}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default UserList;
```

and UserCreate

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class UserCreate extends React.Component {
    render() {

        return (
            <div>
            <Link to="/user">Back</Link>
               <h1>form design wil go here</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default UserCreate;
```

it is displaying the /user, but after redirecting to /user/create, it is not working

I have tried [this](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-nested-routes/) and [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-router-dom-4-nested-example?file=views%2FNested.js), and some more similar, but they are not useful to me.

[here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-router-dom-4-nested-example-qwkqsa) is a working example, I have tried.

I am not sure, even this is possible or not.

Comment: You made misspelling. usre instead of user :-)
Also, you're export default UserList, so if you're importing it you need to miss brackets
`import UserList from '...'`

Comment: both URLs are the same in Link and Route, so that is not the problem, and I have updated the URLs to user.

Answer (score 0):

You have written wrong path in to , it should be user instead of usre

```
  render() {
return (
  <div>
    <h1>user List will be here</h1>
    <Link to="/user/create">create User</Link>
    <Route path="/user/create" component={UserCreate} />
  </div>
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You're using export default so

```
import UserList from './user/userList';
import UserCreate from './create';
```

instead of

```
import { UserList } from './user/userList';
import {UserCreate} from './create';
```

Comment: I have tried, but it is throwing an error:-  
./src/user/create.js
Attempted import error: 'UserCreate' is not exported from './create'.

Comment: Updated. 
If you're using default export, you need to miss brackets in import